# Account creation on ACMEv1 is disabled - Let's Encrypt

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ssl, lets-encrypt, acme

How could I update https://github.com/cliftonm/acme to ACMEv2

The error:

> using server https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/ Account creation on
> ACMEv1 is disabled. Please upgrade your ACME client to a version that
> supports ACMEv2 / RFC 8555. See End of Life Plan for ACMEv1 for
> details.

Answer (score 0):

I most time generate valid certificates from here https://www.sslforfree.com it will only take few minutes

[image]

Comment: That is not an answer, but an alternative